# How to pass httpOptions in aws-sdk DocumentClient constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I am having serious performance issues with aws-sdk when I deploy my application to AWS. 
I'm using it like below:

```
wrapper = {
    accessKeyId: "YOURACCESSKEY",
    secretAccessKey: "YOURSECRETKEY",
    region: "us-east-1",
    endpoint: new AWS.Endpoint('http://localhost:8000')
};

AWS.config.update(wrapper);

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports ={"docClient":docClient};
```

I researched and found that - https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/900 - we can specify httpOptions in the aws so that keepAlive is enabled.

My questions is, how do I specify the httpOptions in the AWS-sdk constructor above:

```
var dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB({
  region: "ap-southeast-2",
  httpOptions: {
  agent: new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  keepAlive: true
  })
}
```

});

how to add this to the wrapper config. It doesn't accept any extra httpOptions key in AWS.config.update

Comment: Did you try `AWS.config.update({httpOptions:{}},true)` ? `true` stands for allow extra keys ...

Answer (score 6):

It should be something like this..

```
new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    service: new AWS.DynamoDB({
      region: "ap-southeast-2",
      httpOptions: {
        agent: new Https.Agent({ keepAlive: true })
      }
    })
  })
```

It has to be added to DocumentClient, not the DynamoDB itself.